# PHP Warning: Unknown: POST Content-Length of 68 bytes exceeds the limit of 10 bytes in Unknown on line 0,

Tags: php

I have error

PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 68 bytes exceeds the limit of **10** bytes in Unknown on line 0

but the change in php.ini memory_limit is not helping at all.

I have no idea how to fix this.

The problem occures when I try send ajax post request to server (the post data dissapear).

Comment: 10 bytes? the default is 2Mb. Try changing in .htaccess... `php_value post_max_size 2M`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the setting of

```
post_max_size
```

in your `php.ini`. 10 bytes sounds a bit like an undesired misconfiguration.